# Rails 4 Wick_pdf sends attaches blank pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-attachments, ruby-on-rails-4.2, wicked-pdf

I'm using wick_pdf in my Rails 4 app to convert several html templates into pdfs. I then attach these pdfs to an outbound email. The email and the pdfs are sending correctly, but there is an additional blank pdf (occasionally not completely) that gets sent along with my desired pdfs. I've attached my code below. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
def approval_notification(id)
    @user = User.find(id)

    esign = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string pdf: "esign", template: "disclosures/pdfs/esign_pdf.html.erb", formats: :html, encoding: "UTF-8") 

    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Congratulations! You have been approved!') do |format|
       format.html 
       format.pdf do
          attachments['Electronic_Signature.pdf'] = esign
       end
    end
end
```

**Update:**

Alright, I managed to fix the issue. I still don't completely understand what was wrong so please explain if you know. The revised code is below:

```
def approval_notification(id)
    @user = User.find(id)

    esign = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string pdf: "esign", template: "disclosures/pdfs/esign_pdf.html.erb", formats: :html, encoding: "UTF-8") 

    attachments['Electronic_Signature.pdf'] = esign

    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Congratulations! You have been approved!') 
 end
```